# how to destroy the session?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, logout

i have a session script but i do not know how to destroy it along with the cookies. i am having an error: The webpage at "website" has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer. i do not know the proper destoy script need.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['manager'])){
header("location:ADMINLOGIN.php");
exit();
}
//Be sure to check that this manager SESSION value is in fact in the database
$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["id"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["manager"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["password"]); //filter everything but numbers and letters 
//Run mySQL qquery to be sure that this person is an admin and that thier password session var equals the database information
//Connect to the MySQL database
include"CONFIG.php";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM administrator WHERE ID='$managerID' AND USERNAME='$manager' AND PASSWORD='$password' LIMIT 1");//query the person
//MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE
$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);//count the row nums
if($existCount==0){//evvaluate the count
echo "Your login session data is not on record in the database";
exit();
}
```

?>

i have found this script but it is not destroying the cookies.

```
<?php
// Finds all server sessions
session_start();
// Stores in Array
$_SESSION = array();
// Swipe via memory
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
// Prepare and swipe cookies
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
// clear cookies and sessions
setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
    $params["path"], $params["domain"],
    $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
);
}
// Just in case.. swipe these values too
ini_set('session.gc_max_lifetime', 0);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);
// Completely destory our server sessions..
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: does your adminlogin.php script include that session code? If so, you're simply redirecting to itself, causing your loop error.

Comment: i already deleted the session code. it worked thanks. but i was wondering if my session_destroy script is working?

Comment: and also i was using the same script a while ago and it was working fine.

Comment: your script would log out EVERYONE, by destroying ALL session files, not just the one of the person you're logging out.

Answer (score 0):

the header should be like this

```
header("location: ADMINLOGIN.php");
                 ^ //space should present otherwise  it is not redirecting properly.
```